# C++ setw equivalent for Lua?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to print out information in a form of a table where the spacing between never changes, kind of like setw from c++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`string.format()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.format). Formatting reference is same as in ISO C's `sprintf()` and `printf()`. For quick reference you may use e.g. [this website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

```
print(string.format("%10d%10d%10d", 114, 523, 15224))
```

will result in:

```
       114       523     15224
```

Basically you can go with (for integers):

```
function printTable(t, length)
    for _,row in pairs(t) do
        local format = ""
        for i=1,#row do format = format .. "%" .. length .. "d" end
        print(string.format(format, table.unpack(row)))
    end
end
```

It is not the most efficient way but it will do the work:

```
> S = {{432, 324, 5325, 4356}, {4325, 5643, 223, 543}, {234, 1, 23, 656}}
> printTable(S, 8)
     432     324    5325    4356
    4325    5643     223     543
     234       1      23     656
```

Comment: `print` also automatically adds a tab between the string representation of its arguments, e.g. `print(114, 523, 15224)` will output `114\t523\t15224`. You may want to include in the answer a way to unpack a table (I am not sure it's required in the question, but however).

Comment: Indeed it adds tabulature but it is not how `setw` works. Another thing is that it won't make them equal in table form which OP wanted to achieve, @user6245072.

Comment: Right, I didn't quite understand what it should have ouput but the new edited answer helps. +1